# Google maps API geocoding returns same coordinates for two different places

Tags: google-maps, geocoding

I'm trying to get the coords for these POI but Google Geocoding returns wrong coords, the same coords for both addresses. In the Google Maps they work fine. How should I construct a correct URL for them?

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Paleo+Enetiko+Frourio,+Corfu+491+00+Greece

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Vlacherna+monastery,+Corfu+491+00+Greece
```

Comment: Strange. It definitely works for other POIs like "Cologne Cathedral".

Comment: It also works for me for many different POI places, but for some it does not work correctly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are "places" not postal addresses.  They both resolve to the same "address" as far as the geocoder is concerned ("Corfu, Greece").  If you need to include the "place name" (you don't have a complete postal address), use the [Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/)

Some major points of interest are included in the geocoding database (like "Eiffel Tower", "Statue of Liberty", "Cologne Cathedral") but not all.

Comment: But why it works for different places? E.g. as Pekka mentioned Cologne Cathedral: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Cologne+Cathedral,+Cologne+Germany

Comment: Some major points of interest are included in the geocoding database (like "Eiffel Tower", "Statue of Liberty", "Cologne Cathedral") but not all.

Answer (score 3):

They are both resolving to the same ADDRESS - since only a name is given instead of a street address.  Try this:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/queryautocomplete/json?input=Paleo+Enetiko+Frourio,+Corfu+491+00+Greece&key=YOUR_API_KEY

That returns:

```
"description": "Paleo Enetiko Frourio, Corfu, 491 00, Greece",
"place_id": "ChIJc8Bxy-ddWxMRhASx_pNTDTU",
```

And then calling with the place_id:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJc8Bxy-ddWxMRhASx_pNTDTU&key=YOUR_KEY_HERE

That'll do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, but your request URL returns zero results.

Comment: Naw - it's all working now - I even submitted my API KEY momentarily, which I'll be destroying now because the internet never forgets...

Comment: You have to use 'queryautocomplete' and not 'autocomplete' which I'd put at first...

Comment: Thanks very much :) Works fine now.