# Google Maps geocode returns ZERO_RESULTS

Tags: google-maps

I have an address of a gaz station (without the street).
I enter the address in Google-Maps and it finds it.
I try it with the API
 $geocode=file_get_contents("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".urlencode($name)."&sensor=false&language=iw&region=il");
and it returns ZERO_RESULTS

Comment: Can you show an example?

Comment: Yes, I have about 300 examples but the only problem is that they are in Hebrew (in Israel).
Here is one example:
תחנת דלק טן ראש פינה
If you copy it and put it in Google-Maps, it will find it for you.
If you do the following
 $geocode=file_get_contents("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".urlencode($name)."&sensor=false&language=iw&region=il");
It will return 
stdClass Object ( [results] => Array ( ) [status] => ZERO_RESULTS ) 
The language and region parameters are not needed, and I added them when I thought it might help.

Comment: I see. There was a similar question recently, I think the answer applies to your situation as well: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33982946/187606

Comment: Where can I find it? Do you have a link to it?

Comment: It's in my comment, underneath

Comment: I searched there and could find it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google maps API geocoding returns same coordinates for two different places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33982946/google-maps-api-geocoding-returns-same-coordinates-for-two-different-places)